# Confirm Chrome navigation dialog in WebdriverIO

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, integration-testing, webdriver-io

Is there a way how to confirm following dialog in WebdriverIO:

[image: chrome_confirm_navigation]

Answer (score 1):

After all, alertAccept() call can handle this.

http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/alertAccept.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to do with alertAccept() in webdriverIO then give this a try :

**dismiss or accept it:**

```
browser.execute(() =>{
       window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
             e.trigger({ type: 'mousedown', which: 13 });
      }
});

// Note: 13 is the key code for enter. And 27 is the key code for escape.
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

IWebElement body = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
body.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

Comment: In WebdriverIO I tried browser.keys("U+E007"), which is equivalent to you proposal. But that doesn't work neither.